# Python - Regex on large log file

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I've got a ~3000 line long log file and I need to find the first occurrence of some string. Which way would be the best/most efficient way to go about doing it?

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    match = re.search(r'^EXHAUST.*', f.read(), re.MULTILINE)
```

or

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.match(r'EXHAUST.*', line)
```

or is there a better way I'm not thinking of?

Comment: How large is "large"?

Comment: Well, if you only need the first occurrence - that reading string by string and breaking after you have found your substring will save you some time most likely.

Comment: Does the line begin with the string (as your re indicates), and is the string hard-coded or a pattern?  Generally if it is a fixed string then using string methods are the way to go, rather than `re`.

Comment: @Lutz Horn It's ~3000 lines long

Comment: @Ripread That's a small file.

Comment: @Lutz Horn Sorry for the confusion. Question is changed

Comment: It's not about confusion. But since you ask for an efficient way to parse a file you call large, it matters how large the file really is. With 3k lines it so small that it doesn't matter which approach you choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case as a more pythonic way you can use `str.startswith` :

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('EXHAUST') :
           #do stuff
```

But about using `re.search` vs `re.match` if you want to match the string from beginning its more efficient that use `re.match` that has been designed for this aim.

Answer (score 1):

I like your second one, but performance wise since your regex is really simple you can use the startswith method

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = line.startswith('EXHAUST')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can practically check the approximate time used by algorithm via something as simple as Python's datetime library, for example:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.now()
# insert your code here #
end = datetime.datetime.now()

result = end - start
print(result)
```

The thing is, with 3000 lines time consumption for the python algorithm to find the phrase is low with both methods. However, from my testings first method is a bit faster if text is located close to the end of text. I tested a 454kb text file with over 3000 lines, most lines being whole paragraphs. Figures being about 0.09s for (below). However, I have to mention that without ^ regex symbol for matching the start of a string, time taken to complete the task was only 0.04s.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    match = re.search(phrase, f.read())
```

versus 0.12s for

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        i += 1
        match = re.match(phrase, line)
            if match:
            break;
```

Here break is needed, otherwise match object would be the last occurrence found and I used for finding out in which line we found the match. Because .start and .end methods for position otherwise would be relative to the line we're on. On search method, however, you could get the match position via .start and .end match object methods by default.

Yet in my test case, first occurrence was near the end of the .txt file so if it was closer to start 2nd method will prevail, because it would stop searching at that line, whereas first method's time consumption stays constant.

Unless you're doing this for competitive coding (where Python is probably not the best pick anyway) both methods take very little time anyway.